# Networking programming skills under UNIX environment

Tags: unix

Greeting,

I'm .NET programmer and I've never programmed for UNIX. 
Now, I'm planing to start developing my networking programming skills under UNIX environment and I do not know what flavor of UNIX OS I should start and and what language start with too.
I'm thinking to start with Java as alanguage to program with but what UNIX OS should I start with.

please advice.
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with Linux. Any distrubution.

Comment: @user548219 is there any difference to program for Linux or unix?

Comment: Absolutely speaking, yes, there are some differences.  Given that you are just starting, I believe it's safe to say that you will not encounter any meaningful differences.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Mandriva.  It's not too far removed from the Windows experience, and it has worked out of the box for me.  (I've used it since before it was labeled "Mandriva").  The live cd's are pretty good, too. I recommend booting up one and trying it out before committing to any distro.

After that, find a good network programming reference. Beej's covers everything I've needed:
[link](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html)